# How to Rotate an ImageSource in .NET MAUI?

Tags: android, maui

I'm currently working on a .NET MAUI project and I'm facing a challenge when trying to rotate an ImageSource. I've already extensively searched through the official documentation and forums, but haven't been able to find a clear solution.

I would like to know if anyone could guide me on the best way to perform the rotation of an ImageSource in .NET MAUI. I want to save the ImageSource into my device, and I'm struggling to find a way to do that.

Any code examples or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You don’t rotate the ImageSource.  You can modify the underlying bitmap to set the EXIF orientation, or to rotate the pixel data, or you can rotate the Image control in the UI.

Comment: I would suggest googling, how to do this for Android and iOS

Comment: Do you mean [Rotate Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/transforms?view=net-maui-8.0#rotate-transform)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is no code i only want to know how can i rotate a ImageSource/Stream or byte data throught the MAUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason said, we could set the EXIF orientation information for an image.
You may use [ExifInterface Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.exifinterface?view=net-android-34.0) to read or write Exif tags for an image.
Suppose there is an image, and we want to let it Rotate 180 degrees,

```
string imagePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "1.png");
       
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
exifInterface.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagOrientation,"3");
exifInterface.SaveAttributes();

myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imagePath);
```

Please note that `ExifInterface.TagOrientation, "3"`, the value 3 means upside down. And for the meanings of different values, you may refer to [Android ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface).

---

You can see the pink triangle rotate 180 degree.

[image]

Hope it helps!